Reactstrap dropdownMenu
I am using container="body" in dropDownMenu but by using this the styling is removed from the menu. how to preserve the  existing styles of the dropDownMenu
.dropdown-menu[data-popper-placement]:not([data-popper-placement^=top-]) {
    margin-top: 0.4rem !important;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
    // border: 5px solid red !important;
    min-width: 160px !important;
    max-width: fit-content !important;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    background-color: $white;
    .dropdown-item {
      height: auto !important;
  
      &:hover {
        background: var(--bs-primary-lighter) !important;
      }
  
      &:active {
        background: var(--bs-primary-lighter) !important;
      }
    }
}

